# how to use OpenCV with VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

I have heard about EmguCv, OpenCV wrapper for VS.NET
I dindn't understand how to use it on VB.NET 2008.
is it different with OpenCV usage?
anyone can help me, may you have ebook, tutorial etc.
thank you so much..

Answer (score 1):

There are naturally some slight differences when using EMGU. You best port of call are the examples I know that the downloaded examples with EMGU are lacking in VB examples. With thanks to giusdisa on the EMGU forums who has provided a web site with more examples

http://www.motoreitaliano.net/emgu/default.htm

There are no books but I would recommend going over these examples and get them running if you get any errors take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EMGU_Image_Processing.aspx. While it is for C# it has details on errors that can occur and trouble shooting problems. If you encounter any other errors then please let me know. I am in the process of re-writing the article for VB so it would be useful to account for alternative errors.

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris